# oracle report lexical parameter

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I am using oracle report and have problem with "SELECT ALL" here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM company A, seller B
WHERE a.id = b.id 
&(P)Company_id
```

and in my after parameter in oracle report i use

```
begin 
    if (:(V)Company_id is not null and :(V)Company_id<> '0')
       :(P)Company_id:= ' and a.id ='||:(V)Company_id;
    end if;
    return (true)`
end;
```

if the id is all digit like `000123` works fine, but if id like `([L]00123)` the result is show all data. need help with my lexical parameter.

Comment: What is `(V)` in `(V)Company_id`? (the same goes for `(P)`).

Comment: It should be P for parameter so became PCompany_id, while V for variable became VCompany_id.

Answer (score 1):

Information you post is misleading. I've been using Oracle Reports *for ages*, and I've never seen syntax you use. Code you wrote doesn't even compile; how would it work, then (which is what you claim)? There's no `(V)something` syntax at all.

Anyway, from my point of view, you don't need a lexical parameter but a simple `OR` condition, e.g.

```
select *
from company a join seller b on b.id = a.id
where (a.id = :par_company_id or :par_company_id is null)
```

- the first part of it, `a.id = :par_company_id` will return rows whose ID is equal to value you enter in the parameter form
- the second part, `or :par_company_id is null` will return all rows if you leave the parameter value *empty*

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought you'd get an error from that rather than all data, but maybe Reports does something weird in that scenario. Anyway, it looks like you just need to enclose the passed-in value in single quotes, which you will need to escape; so instead of this line:

```
   :(P)Company_id:= ' and a.id ='||:(V)Company_id;
```

use:

```
   :(P)Company_id:= ' and a.id = ''' || :(V)Company_id || '''';
```

although it would be better if you could keep it as a bind variable. I'm not familiar with Reports but something like this might work:

```
select *
from company A
join seller B
on a.id = b.id
where &(V)Company_id is null or a.id = &(V)Company_id
```

(I've switched to ANSI join syntax as well...)

Comment: :(P)Company_id:= ' and a.id = ''' || :(V)Company_id || ''''; 
i try that work with digit id like 000123 but when id like 'L00123' that query will show all data, not 'L00123' data

Comment: @gehirnseele - even with those extra single quotes? How and where is `(P)Company_id` defined? Maybe that's a number data type, or a string but too small, and an error assigning the value to it is being suppressed somewhere?

Comment: i define PCompany_id on query oracle report, and VCompany_id is another parameter that i use on "After Parameter Form".

input goes to VCompany_id while Pcompany stay in main query

Comment: the requirement :
if u input blank on text box Company_Id will select all company
if u input specific id it will search that id